# data inserted into db after spring transaction rollback

Tags: spring-3, rollback, spring-transactions

I'm testing my declartive transaction configuration with following testcase:

I try to insert 2 record into a table with 4 columns(id, content, position, time) while position is a UNIQUE index. I use mysql 5.5 with innoDB engine, and develop the test with Spring 3.2.2, Mybatis 3.2.2, Mybatis-Spring 1.2.0. below is the sql to create the database and table with experimental data inserted.

```
    CREATE DATABASE `development` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
    USE `development`;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `content` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
      `position` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `position` (`position`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=97 ;

    INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `content`, `position`, `time`) VALUES (1, 'test', 0, 1368164281),(2, '测试内容', 1, 1368164364),(44, 'bbb', 2, 1368431459),(45, 'ccc', 3, 1368431459),
```

Here is the configuration xml service.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
    <bean id="testDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${test.driverClass}" />
        <property name="url" value="${test.jdbcUrl}" />
        <property name="username" value="${test.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${test.password}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${test.miniPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${test.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${test.initialPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${test.maxIdleTime}" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${test.acquireIncrement}" />
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="${test.acquireRetryAttempts}" />
        <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="${test.acquireRetryDelay}" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="${test.testConnectionOnCheckin}" />
        <property name="automaticTestTable" value="${test.automaticTestTable}" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${test.idleConnectionTestPeriod}" />
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="${test.checkoutTimeout}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="testDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="add*" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="testServiceOperation" expression="execution(* com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl.addRecords(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="testServiceOperation" />
    </aop:config>

    <bean id="TestService" class="com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl" />
</beans>
```

Below is the test-mapper-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mybatis-spring="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring-1.2.xsd">

    <bean id="recordMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="testSqlSessionFactory" />
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is the serviceImpl class:

```
package com.ssports.test.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;

import com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper;
import com.ssports.test.model.Record;
import com.ssports.test.model.RecordExample;
import com.ssports.util.SpringHelper;

public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestServiceImpl.class);
    private static RecordMapper mapper = SpringHelper.getBean("recordMapper");

    public List<Record> getAll() {
        return mapper.selectByExample(new RecordExample());
    }

    public Record getRecordbyId(int id) {
        return mapper.selectByPrimaryKey(id);
    }

    public void addRecords(List<Record> recordList) throws Exception {
           for (Record record : recordList) {
                logger.info(record.getPosition() + ":" + record.getTime());
                    mapper.insert(record);
        }
    }

}
```

the test code is:
    package com.ssports.db;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;

import com.ssports.test.model.Record;
import com.ssports.test.service.TestService;
import com.ssports.util.SpringHelper;

public class TransTest {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransTest.class);

        TestService service = SpringHelper.getBean("TestService");
        List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();

        Record record1 = service.getRecordbyId(1);
        Record record4 = new Record();
        record4.setContent("ddd");
        record4.setPosition(4);
        record4.setTime((int) (new Long(System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000));

        records.add(record4);
        records.add(record1);

        DataSourceTransactionManager txManager = SpringHelper.getBean("txManager");
        try {
            service.addRecords(records);
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException ex) {            
            logger.info(ex.getMessage());
        }

        List<Record> recordlist = service.getAll();
        for (Record item : recordlist) {
            logger.info(item.getId() + ":" + item.getContent() + ":"
                    + new Date((long) item.getTime() * 1000) + ":"
                    + item.getPosition());
        }

    }

}
```

I run the application, and here is the log:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method [get*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly]
DEBUG: org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method [add*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT]
DEBUG: org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method [get*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly]
DEBUG: org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method [add*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT]
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl.addRecords]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Acquired Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@6650af3b] for JDBC transaction
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Switching JDBC Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@6650af3b] to manual commit
INFO : com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl - 4:1368602606
INFO : com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl - 0:1368164281
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@6650af3b]
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@6650af3b] after transaction
INFO : com.ssports.db.TransTest - 
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
### The error may involve com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.insert-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: insert into test (id, content, position,        time)     values (?, ?, ?,        ?)
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
; SQL []; Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
INFO : com.ssports.db.TransTest - 1:test:Fri May 10 13:38:01 CST 2013:0
INFO : com.ssports.db.TransTest - 2:测试内容:Fri May 10 13:39:24 CST 2013:1
INFO : com.ssports.db.TransTest - 44:bbb:Mon May 13 15:50:59 CST 2013:2
INFO : com.ssports.db.TransTest - 45:ccc:Mon May 13 15:50:59 CST 2013:3
INFO : com.ssports.db.TransTest - 98:ddd:Wed May 15 15:23:26 CST 2013:4
```

you can see that while the exception throw, the transaction manager roll the database back, but a record still insert into it.

Is there anyone can tell what wrong here, or is it a bug?

**updated**

I tried programatic transaction with code below, of course comment the lines in service.xml to disable the aop and txAdvice. after that,it works:

```
package com.ssports.test.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition;

import com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper;
import com.ssports.test.model.Record;
import com.ssports.test.model.RecordExample;
import com.ssports.util.SpringHelper;

public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestServiceImpl.class);
    private static RecordMapper mapper = SpringHelper.getBean("recordMapper");
    private static DataSourceTransactionManager txManager = SpringHelper.getBean("txManager");
    private static TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    private static TransactionStatus status = txManager.getTransaction(def);

    public List<Record> getAll() {
        return mapper.selectByExample(new RecordExample());
    }

    public Record getRecordbyId(int id) {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        logger.debug("Thread Name: "+t.getName());
        logger.debug("Thread id: "+t.getId());
        return mapper.selectByPrimaryKey(id);
    }

    public void addRecords(List<Record> recordList) throws Exception {


        try {
        for (Record record : recordList) {
            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            logger.debug("Thread Name: "+t.getName());
            logger.debug("Thread id: "+t.getId());
            logger.info(record.getPosition() + ":" + record.getTime());
            mapper.insert(record);
        }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.debug("Exception throw");
            logger.debug(ex.getMessage());
            txManager.rollback(status);
            throw ex;
        }

        txManager.commit(status);
    }

}
```

Here is the log:

```
2013-05-16 11:23:17 625 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean - Parsed configuration file: 'class path resource [config/mybatis-config.xml]'
2013-05-16 11:23:17 929 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean - Parsed mapper file: 'file [/home/zhangzhi/workspace-STS/MultiDb/target/classes/com/ssports/uc/mybatis/mappers/UcMemberMapper.xml]'
2013-05-16 11:23:17 948 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean - Parsed configuration file: 'class path resource [config/mybatis-config.xml]'
2013-05-16 11:23:18 247 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean - Parsed mapper file: 'file [/home/zhangzhi/workspace-STS/MultiDb/target/classes/com/ssports/site/mybatis/mappers/adMapper.xml]'
2013-05-16 11:23:18 264 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean - Parsed configuration file: 'class path resource [config/mybatis-config.xml]'
2013-05-16 11:23:18 316 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean - Parsed mapper file: 'file [/home/zhangzhi/workspace-STS/MultiDb/target/classes/com/ssports/test/mybatis/mappers/RecordMapper.xml]'
2013-05-16 11:23:18 476 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean - Parsed configuration file: 'class path resource [config/mybatis-config.xml]'
2013-05-16 11:23:18 546 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean - Parsed mapper file: 'file [/home/zhangzhi/workspace-STS/MultiDb/target/classes/com/ssports/uc/mybatis/mappers/UcMemberMapper.xml]'
2013-05-16 11:23:18 556 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean - Parsed configuration file: 'class path resource [config/mybatis-config.xml]'
2013-05-16 11:23:18 680 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean - Parsed mapper file: 'file [/home/zhangzhi/workspace-STS/MultiDb/target/classes/com/ssports/site/mybatis/mappers/adMapper.xml]'
2013-05-16 11:23:18 690 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean - Parsed configuration file: 'class path resource [config/mybatis-config.xml]'
2013-05-16 11:23:18 728 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean - Parsed mapper file: 'file [/home/zhangzhi/workspace-STS/MultiDb/target/classes/com/ssports/test/mybatis/mappers/RecordMapper.xml]'
2013-05-16 11:23:18 739 DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2013-05-16 11:23:18 740 DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Acquired Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@6188024d] for JDBC transaction
2013-05-16 11:23:18 747 DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Switching JDBC Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@6188024d] to manual commit
2013-05-16 11:23:18 748 DEBUG: com.ssports.db.TransTest - Get record1.
2013-05-16 11:23:18 749 DEBUG: com.ssports.db.TransTest - Thread Name: main
2013-05-16 11:23:18 749 DEBUG: com.ssports.db.TransTest - Thread id: 1
2013-05-16 11:23:18 749 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl - Thread Name: main
2013-05-16 11:23:18 749 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl - Thread id: 1
2013-05-16 11:23:18 754 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Creating a new SqlSession
2013-05-16 11:23:18 757 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@158b6810]
2013-05-16 11:23:18 776 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction - JDBC Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@6188024d] will be managed by Spring
2013-05-16 11:23:18 777 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.selectByPrimaryKey - ooo Using Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@6188024d]
2013-05-16 11:23:18 783 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.selectByPrimaryKey - ==>  Preparing: select id, content, position, time from test where id = ? 
2013-05-16 11:23:18 807 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.selectByPrimaryKey - ==> Parameters: 1(Integer)
2013-05-16 11:23:18 824 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@158b6810]
2013-05-16 11:23:18 824 DEBUG: com.ssports.db.TransTest - Invoking service method[addRecords]
2013-05-16 11:23:18 824 DEBUG: com.ssports.db.TransTest - Thread Name: main
2013-05-16 11:23:18 824 DEBUG: com.ssports.db.TransTest - Thread id: 1
2013-05-16 11:23:18 824 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl - Thread Name: main
2013-05-16 11:23:18 824 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl - Thread id: 1
2013-05-16 11:23:18 824 INFO : com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl - 4:1368674598
2013-05-16 11:23:18 824 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Fetched SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@158b6810] from current transaction
2013-05-16 11:23:18 825 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.insert - ooo Using Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@6188024d]
2013-05-16 11:23:18 825 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.insert - ==>  Preparing: insert into test (id, content, position, time) values (?, ?, ?, ?) 
2013-05-16 11:23:18 825 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.insert - ==> Parameters: null, ddd(String), 4(Integer), 1368674598(Integer)
2013-05-16 11:23:18 826 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@158b6810]
2013-05-16 11:23:18 826 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl - Thread Name: main
2013-05-16 11:23:18 826 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl - Thread id: 1
2013-05-16 11:23:18 826 INFO : com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl - 0:1368164281
2013-05-16 11:23:18 826 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Fetched SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@158b6810] from current transaction
2013-05-16 11:23:18 826 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.insert - ooo Using Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@6188024d]
2013-05-16 11:23:18 826 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.insert - ==>  Preparing: insert into test (id, content, position, time) values (?, ?, ?, ?) 
2013-05-16 11:23:18 826 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.insert - ==> Parameters: null, test(String), 0(Integer), 1368164281(Integer)
2013-05-16 11:23:18 871 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@158b6810]
2013-05-16 11:23:18 871 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl - Exception throw
2013-05-16 11:23:18 871 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.service.TestServiceImpl - 
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'position'
### The error may involve com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.insert-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: insert into test (id, content, position,        time)     values (?, ?, ?,        ?)
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'position'
; SQL []; Duplicate entry '0' for key 'position'; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'position'
2013-05-16 11:23:18 871 DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
2013-05-16 11:23:18 871 DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@6188024d]
2013-05-16 11:23:18 907 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Transaction synchronization rolling back SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@158b6810]
2013-05-16 11:23:18 907 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Transaction synchronization closing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@158b6810]
2013-05-16 11:23:18 908 DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@6188024d] after transaction
2013-05-16 11:23:18 909 DEBUG: com.ssports.db.TransTest - Exception throw
2013-05-16 11:23:18 909 DEBUG: com.ssports.db.TransTest - 
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'position'
### The error may involve com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.insert-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: insert into test (id, content, position,        time)     values (?, ?, ?,        ?)
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'position'
; SQL []; Duplicate entry '0' for key 'position'; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'position'
2013-05-16 11:23:18 909 DEBUG: com.ssports.db.TransTest - Checking Result
2013-05-16 11:23:18 909 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Creating a new SqlSession
2013-05-16 11:23:18 909 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@2c8446f7] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
2013-05-16 11:23:18 929 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction - JDBC Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@6188024d] will not be managed by Spring
2013-05-16 11:23:18 929 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.selectByExample - ooo Using Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@6188024d]
2013-05-16 11:23:18 929 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.selectByExample - ==>  Preparing: select id, content, position, time from test 
2013-05-16 11:23:18 930 DEBUG: com.ssports.test.mapper.RecordMapper.selectByExample - ==> Parameters: 
2013-05-16 11:23:18 931 DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@2c8446f7]
2013-05-16 11:23:18 932 INFO : com.ssports.db.TransTest - 1:test:Fri May 10 13:38:01 CST 2013:0
2013-05-16 11:23:18 932 INFO : com.ssports.db.TransTest - 2:测试内容:Fri May 10 13:39:24 CST 2013:1
2013-05-16 11:23:18 932 INFO : com.ssports.db.TransTest - 44:bbb:Mon May 13 15:50:59 CST 2013:2
2013-05-16 11:23:18 932 INFO : com.ssports.db.TransTest - 45:ccc:Mon May 13 15:50:59 CST 2013:3
```

and here is the SpringHelper Class:

```
package com.ssports.util;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class SpringHelper {

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(SpringHelper.class);

    private static ApplicationContext cx = null;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getBean(String beanId){
        if(cx == null){
          cx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/application-context.xml");
        }
        return (T)cx.getBean(beanId);
    }

    public synchronized static void init(){
        if(cx == null){
          cx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/application-context.xml");
          logger.info("Spring config success!,ApplicationContext set a object");
        }
    }

    public synchronized static void init(String[] paths){

        if(cx == null){
          cx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(paths);
          logger.info("Spring config success!,ApplicationContext set a object");
        }

    }

    public synchronized static void init(String path){

        init(new String[]{path});
    }

}
```

**updated**
I‘ve made a little change on TestServiceImpl, and it's solved, as below:

```
private static RecordMapper mapper;

public void init() {
    if (null == mapper) {
        mapper = (RecordMapper) SpringHelper.getBean("recordMapper");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem:**

I would say that the problem is in your SpringHelper class implementation and how you are using it (namely the static reference in TestServiceImpl). **You might have two Spring contexts initialized** (symptoms for this are contained within the first 4 lines of your log file).

**Why it does not work:**

Transaction+rollback in one context does not have any effect on the DB connection made by the other context (both have their own `testDataSource` and `txManager` beans).

**How to solve it:**

Spring is a dependency injection framework, so I don't see a point for implementing your own dependency lookup strategy. You might want to check `Autowired` annotation for getting depdendencies (such as your `TestServiceImpl.mapper`) in place.

Check Spring documentation and demo projects (e.g. https://github.com/SpringSource/greenhouse) to see how to get the best out of Spring. **Try to use Spring in a standard way**.

**Additional AOP issue:**

Btw. your pointcut definition is not correct as the read-only advice is not covered by that.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. @Pavel Horal

Comment: I've updated the information and my code of SpringHelper Class. May you provide more advice, thanks. I'm new to Spring, and worked on PHP for a couple of years, quite different.

Comment: You've made it a little bit worse. Just remove all 'static' declarations in 'TestServiceImpl'. And follow some basic introductory tutorials on Spring (make sure the tutorials are not old).